# Align a rectangle above a node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am just beginning with tikz, and I am trying to put headers and footers in each page.
I have this code, but here is my (very little) problem:

```
\newcommand\Footer{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[above, yshift=-3] (footer) at (current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{footer.png}};
\draw [fill=otherdarkblue, draw=none] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (\paperwidth,0.2); % I want this to be just above the footer and centered horizontally
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

I want the rectangle to be drawn just above the footer node (the bottom of the rectangle should corresponds to the top of the footer) and horizontally centered regarding the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\Footer{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=south,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (footer) at (current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}};
\node [fill=blue, draw=none,minimum width=\paperwidth,inner ysep=0.1cm,outer sep=0pt] at (footer.north){}; % I want this to be just above the footer and centered horizontally
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(0,0){\Footer}}%
   }

\begin{document}
Some text
\clearpage
Some text again
\end{document}
```

[image]

Same with `background` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\Footer{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=south,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (footer) at (current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{example-image}};
\node [fill=blue, draw=none,minimum width=\paperwidth,inner ysep=0.1cm,outer sep=0pt] at (footer.north){}; % I want this to be just above the footer and centered horizontally
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
contents={\Footer}
}

\begin{document}
Some text
\clearpage
Some text again
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but here you specify the vertical alignment by hand. How to align the bottom of the rectangle to the top of the `footer` node ?

Comment: @Vincent Answer edited.